# WolframAlpha can solve this but Mathematica cannot

Tags: equation-solving

Wolfram|Alpha can solve the following problem:

```
"solve 615+x^2=2^y over integers"
```

It returns the answer

> $x=\pm 59$ and $y=12$

How can one solve the same problem with Mathematica?

I tried

```
Solve[615+x^2==2^y, {x,y}, Integers]
```

which returned

```
During evaluation of In[]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.


(* {{y -> ConditionalExpression[
            Log[615 + x^2] Log[2], 
            (x | Log[615 + x^2]/Log[2]) ∈ Integers]}} *)
```

Comment: There's always `Solve[{615 + x^2 == 2^y, -100 < x < 100}, {x, y}, Integers]`.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: `FindInstance[{615 + x^2 == 2^y, -100 < x < 100}, {x, y}, Integers, 2]`

Comment: @Rick I edit the question to show what is the expected way to pose it, and avoid closing it. Please try to follow this model in the future: 1. state the question/problem explicitly 2. show what you tried, show what you got as a result, and say what you expected to get instead.

Comment: It's an interesting math problem though not so much tied to Mathematica. For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure it can be shown that no solutions exist for "sufficiently large" `y`. Making that size explicit and then checking up to that limit would take work. Basically though, the solution `{x,y}={59,12}` is almost certainly the only one.